# Centos 6 guest can only see 127GB on Hyper-v

Tags: hyper-v, centos6

I created a fixed VHD size 800GB. However, when I try to install CentOS 6 x64 bits OS, it only use 127GB LVM volume. How to install CentOS 6 without using LVM? I want to use all the 800GB disk. Thanks.

Comment: When you go through the installation, just select the option to manually configure the disk.  It's been a while, but go through and remove the suggested partitioning and put in your own scheme without LVM.

Comment: I tried this, use custom partition layer, delete all partitions, it still shows one hard drive sda with 130558MB space. This VHD is 800GB.

Comment: Your subject line is misleading.  The problem is not LVM, the problem is that for some reason CentOS isn't seeing the entire 800GB disk or that it's not configured properly on Hyper-V.  After the Anaconda is started, flip to a virtual console with a shell and run 'fdisk -l /dev/sda' and report back what it says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be presenting your VHD to your VM as an IDE emulated device. I'd suggest you try showing it as SCSI devices or update your Hyper-V setup. I know a bug was filled at least 1.5 years ago about that - I don't know if there's a fix available though. I don't use Hyper-V much.

Without getting too much into details: your virtual IDE disks present itself as an 'ATA-0' device (version 0). This device would supposedly not support LBA48 addressing. System then fallback to 28-bits addressing, showing a limit around 137GB.

Sorry, this isn't really 'clean' answer, but at least you know the issue.

Comment: I found the article in Microsoft site and tried using SCSI, it didn't solve my problem, but I guess this might be the problem. Thanks.  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverhyperv/thread/2f110053-a4bc-4c53-a945-b78481637f66/